# Global section of multiples of the canonical divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Suppose $X$ is a curve over $k$ (say an algebraically closed field) and we know the genus of $X$ is $g$. Let $K$ be a canonical divisor on $X$. Is there anything we can say about $H^0(X,dK)$ for positive integers $d$? Of course by definition, we have that $H^0(X,K)=g$, but do we know anything else? If for example, $g=0$, then we can use Riemann Roch to get that $h^0(dK)=\deg (dK) +1$, but I'm curious to know if we can say anything more specific.

Edit: Via Riemann Roch, $h^0(dK)=h^0(K-dK)+\deg(dK)+1-g=h^0(K-dK)+d(2g-2)+1-g$, but I'm not sure how to get an explicit description with this.

Further edit: By Remark 1.3.2 in Ch.IV.1 of Hartshorne, we have that $h^0(dK)=d\deg K-g+1=d(2g-2)-g+1$ as soon as $d\deg K > \deg K$, that is, as soon as $d(2g-2)>2g-2$. For genus $0$, this is never satisfied, so I don't know how to get a description.

Comment: You can get explicit results for any $d\geq 0$ and any $g$ via Riemann-Roch pretty quickly. If that's not going well for you, please add some detail about where you're getting stuck to the post with an [edit].

Comment: @KReiser Ok, I've added what I've got.

Comment: Well, the material added in the edit is good, but one ought to be slightly more precise (you should split the cases $g=0$, $g=1$, and $g\geq 2$ because there's different behavior - in particular, $h^0(K-dK)$ is not always zero for all $g$ and all $d\geq 0$).

Comment: Just as a note on terminology, the dimensions $h^0(X, dK)$ are called the [*plurigenera*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodaira_dimension#The_plurigenera) of the curve and are used in computing its Kodaira dimension.

Comment: How is $d(2g-2) + 1 - g$ *not* an explicit description of a number in terms of $d$ and $g$? What kind of result do you expect?

Comment: @red_trumpet I am hoping to get vanishing when greater than some specific $d$ in the genus $0$ and genus $1$ cases. But I'm not sure if this is true, so I'm hoping for some enlightenment.

Comment: In genus $0$, the canonical bundle is $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^1}(-2)$, so no positive multiple has global sections. In genus 1, the canonical bundle is $\mathcal{O}_X$, so all multiples are $\mathcal{O}_X$ and have sections. (It's a very important fact that the canonical bundle of $\Bbb P^n$ is $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^n}(-n-1)$ - I would really suggest reviewing that if you don't have that top-of-mind.)